# Why can't I install pip autopy?

Tags: python, pip, autopy

Command used:

```
C:\Users\HP VICTUS>pip install autopy
```

Error message:

```
Collecting autopy
  Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2fg9kj23\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2fg9kj23\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2fg9kj23\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP VICTUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2fg9kj23\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I want to use autopy. Why can't I install pip autopy?

Answer (score -1):

The error message suggests that the installation of autopy failed because of an error with the setuptools_rust module.

To fix this issue, you can try installing `setuptools-rust` by running the following command:

`pip install setuptools-rust`

After Installing try to install `autopy` again.

`pip install autopy`

> Note: If the issue persists, you can also try upgrading `pip`